# slicing n-dimensional numpy array in arbitrary ranges

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

Let's say I have an N-dimensional numpy array and two lists of start and end points.

```
start_points = [0, 3, 1]
end_points = [5, 8, 4]
```

and what I want to do is this:

```
some_slice = my_array[0:5, 3:8, 1:4]
```

I know how to do this when hard-coding it, the question is how do I do it without hard-coding it with an arbitrary number of dimensions

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Yes and how would that help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
some_slice = my_array[tuple(map(slice, start_points, end_points))]
```